# Diagonalizable transmit to submatrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

If $$\begin{pmatrix}
A & B\\
\Large 0 & C
\end{pmatrix}$$ is similar to a diagonal matrix, are $A$ and $C$ also similar to diagonal matrices?

Comment: You may consider its minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment provided indicates, the answer is yes.  The quickest way to see this is to note that a matrix is diagonalizable if and only if its minimal polynomial has no repeated roots.

Let $m$ be the minimal polynomial of the block matrix $M$. Of course, $m(M) = 0$.  However, by block-matrix multiplication, we see that
$$
m(M) = \pmatrix{
m(A) & \star\\
0 & m(C)}
$$ 
so, we deduce that $m(A) = 0$ and $m(C) = 0$.  So, the minimal polynomials of $A$ and $C$ divide $m$.  So, the minimal polynomials of $A$ and $C$ have no repeated roots.  So, both $A$ and $C$ are diagonalizable.